# Secure ajax GET/POST request for server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

suppose I work with some kind of API and my file **server.php** handles the connection to the API service. on my client side I use AJAX call like this:

```
$http({
         url : 'server/server.php',
         method : 'GET',
         data : { getContent : true }
     });
```

in my server.php I handle it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['getContent'])){
    $content = get_content();
}

function get_content(){...}
```

i just wonder what prevents any one send AJAX call with the same getContent parameter and get all my data? how can i secure it and make sure only calls from my application will get the relevant data back?

thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are concerned about CSRF attacks. Read more about this here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

One of the mostly used option to secure your request will be:
- Generate a token and send it with the request for a session. This token can be identified by your WebServer as originating from a specific client for a specific session

Answer (score 4):

## 2022 Update

*This is a 7 year old post and the link in the link-only "accepted" answer is broken.*

So, I'm going to offer a basic walkthrough and a complete model.

Remember, the `$_SESSION` will be preserved even in the AJAX handler, if it's all from the same domain. So, you can use that to check things.

### Use `$_POST`

*I presume you're using `$_POST` and not `$_GET` since you're concerned about security. If not, then much of this might not be important anyway.*

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $post_method = true;
}
```

### Ensure the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is from your own site

```php
if ( (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
&&   ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === "https://example.tld/my_sending_page.php") ) {
  $from_my_server = true;
}
```

If you're not sure what this should be, run a test on your own server to see what this should be:

```php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

### Use a token

This is the hard part, but not too hard.

1. Create the token
2. Set the token in `$_SESSION`
3. Put the token in the AJAX header
4. AJAX responder: confirm the AJAX header token with the `$_SESSION` token

**send_from_me.php**

```php
// Create the token
//$token = md5(rand(10000,99999));  // Not recommended, but possible
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));

// Store in SESSION
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;
```

```js
// Assuming your AJAX is this
const AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();

...
AJAX.open(...);

// This goes inside your AJAX function somewhere after AJAX.open and before AJAX.send
//
AJAX.setRequestHeader("ajax-token", "<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>");
//
// That creates $_SERVER['HTTP_AJAX_TOKEN'] which we can use later

...
AJAX.send(...);
```

**ajax_responder.php**

```php
session_start(); // Must have

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_AJAX_TOKEN'] === $_SESSION["token"]) {
  $token_match = true;
} else {
  echo "No script kiddies!";
  exit();
}

// Now it's safe for your AJAX responder to proceed
```

## Let's put all of this into a working example

**sending_from.php**

```php
<?php

session_start();

$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My AJAX Sender</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      function ajaxFormData(formID, postTo, ajaxUpdate) {

        // Bind a new event listener every time the <form> is changed:
        const FORM = document.getElementById(formID); // <form> by ID
        const FD = new FormData(FORM); // Bind to-send data to form element
        const AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest(); // AJAX handler

        // This runs when AJAX responds
        AJAX.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
          document.getElementById(ajaxUpdate).innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
        } );

        // This runs if AJAX fails
        AJAX.addEventListener( "error", function(event) {
          document.getElementById(ajaxUpdate).innerHTML =  'Oops! Something went wrong.';
        } );

        // Open the POST connection
        AJAX.open("POST", postTo);

        // Add your token header
        AJAX.setRequestHeader("ajax-token", "<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>");

        // Data sent is from the form
        AJAX.send(FD);

      }
    </script>

    <div id="ajax_changes">Replace me with AJAX</div>

      <form id="ajaxForm">
        <input type="text" name="the_simple_response">
        <button type="button" onclick="ajaxFormData('ajaxForm', 'ajax_responder.php', 'ajax_changes');">Send my Secure AJAX</button>
      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**ajaxcheck.inc.php**

```php
<?php

// $mysite = 'https://example.tld'; // manually set host
$mysite = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // automatically retrieve host

// All in one test
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
&& ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === "$mysite/my_sending_page.php"))
&& ($_SERVER['HTTP_AJAX_TOKEN'] === $_SESSION["token"])) {
  
  $ajax_legit = true;
  
} else {
  
  echo "No script kiddies!";
  exit();
  
}

?>
```

**ajax_responder.php**

```php
<?php

session_start();

// Do all that checking we're learning about by neatly including the file above
require_once('ajaxcheck.inc.php');

// Process your AJAX
echo $_POST['the_simple_response'];

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

> i just wonder what prevents any one send AJAX call with the same getContent parameter and get all my data?

Nothing. This URL is public thus anyone can make requests to it.

> how can i secure it and make sure only calls from my application will get the relevant data back?

You can pass additional data (for example, some hashed value) that is verified on the server side.

```
$http({
     url : 'server/server.php',
     method : 'GET',
     data : { getContent : true, hash : '0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945' }
 });
```

and

```
if(isset($_GET['getContent']))
{
    if(isset($_GET['hash']) && validateHash($_GET['hash']))
    {
        $content = get_content();
    }
}

function get_content(){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

> i just wonder what prevents any one send AJAX call with the same getContent parameter and get all my data?

The same way you would protect the data in any other request (e.g. with user authentication). There's nothing special about Ajax in regards to HTTP as far as the server is concerned.

> how can i secure it and make sure only calls from my application will get the relevant data back?

You can't. The user can always inspect what their browser is asking the server for and replicate it.

Generally, people authenticate users rather than applications.