# How to securely send POST data between JQuery and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I would like to send data from a Jquery script to a php page using POST.
My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://mywebsite.com/add_data.php',
data: {value1: some_value, 
    value2: 123, 
    value3: ABC 

},
```

My php script captures the data and records them in MySQL database.

```
$myvalue1 = $_POST['value1'];
$myvalue2 = $_POST['value2'];
$myvalue3 = $_POST['value3'];
```

The problem is that since JS code is visible in the source code, anyone can submit anything to my database...

Is there an easy way to make it more secure and prevent this from happening?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't this be handled at the web server level, something like apache authentication and authorization?

Comment: use token (token generate on server side. when user hit ajax then first verify the token) also read the laravel csrf token documentation

Comment: Use CSRF Tokens and verify them, this will ensure request is made from your server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883223/secure-ajax-get-post-request-for-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912937/how-to-send-secure-ajax-requests-with-php-and-jquery

Comment: The problem is that both files are not on the same server...

Answer (score 3):

All data from the client always MUST be validated and sanitized, because all data from the client can be modificated/falsificated.